# Pass synched Realm to other Activity

Tags: kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

When I try to access the synched Realm from e.g. Main Activity I always get the error lateinit var not initialised.
I can successful open a database on the device and also the synched Database. But because the open of the synched Database must be in "run blocking" I don't know how to access "synchedRealm" then. Can't pass it to Main Activity.
I am sure its kind of fundamental knowledge I don't get out of the Kotlin/Realm documentation because English  is not my primary language.

Thank you for your help!!!

```
In another Activity: MyApp:

....

 runBlocking {
    // Neuen User Registrieren
    // app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser(email, pw)
    // once registered, you can log in with the user credentials

    val appid: String = "MYAppId"
    val apikey: String = "MyApiKey"
  
    val app: App = App.create(
        AppConfiguration.Builder(appid)
            .log(LogLevel.ALL)
            .build()
    )


    val user_api = app.login(io.realm.kotlin.mongodb.Credentials.apiKey(apikey))
  
            val config = SyncConfiguration.Builder(
                user_api,
                setOf(MyClass::class)
            )
                .initialSubscriptions { realm ->
                    add(
                        realm.query<PersonCollection>(
                            "MyField == $0",
                            "Mustermann"
                        ),
                        "subscription name"
                    )
                }
                .build()

            val realmSynced = Realm.open(config)
}
```

I tried also the above code in an object{} or the runblocking{} in an init{} block and dozend other things

```
In Mainactivity:

lateinit var realm:Realm
lateinit var realmSynched:Realm

...


realm=MyApp.Databaseobject.realm //Works for Database on device

realmSynched= ????  //How to initialise this ???
```

Comment: I am not real clear on the question but generally speaking, you don't 'pass' Realm around; passing realm objects are more commonplace. You also appear to already have the code to open a synced Realm in the question `val realmSynced = Realm.open(config)` so... do it the same way each time you want to access it. Often times a singleton pattern or a global call is used but I am not a Kotlin guy so you'll need to research that option.

Comment: Thank you. In the SDK version before you could get the instance of the realm in an other Activity with "getInstance(RealmConfiguration configuration)", now in the new SDK they say a Singleton is used. I can work with this Singleton if it is a offline database. However the opening of the Sync Database and Login must be in this "runblocking{}" and outside of this I dont know how to access this Singleton. I think this is my problem :)